# Slow performance if a character present after $ in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

```
var longstr = new Array(30000).join("a");
longstr.replace(/(.*?)\s*$d/, "$1");
```

I have the above code to trim the white space present at the end of the string. The above code takes lot of time to execute (~3sec), the character "d" which is there after $ symbol is the reason for this bottleneck, removing the "d" resolves the issue.

I need to know what happens if a character is present after $ symbol.

Comment: The `d` is just matching the literal character `d`.  Not sure why that's having such a performance impact.

Comment: Maybe the engine can't optimize to start looking from the end of the string instead of the beginning. If it looks from the beginning it will literally check every substring of the string that starts at position 0 whether it matches `(.*?)\s*$`. I.e. given `aaaaa`, it would test `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, `aaaa`, `aaaaa`.

Comment: @FelixKling Seems believable :)

Comment: Also note that `.*?` is one of the worst constructs you can put in a regular expression. It a typical root cause for performance problems. Putting it at the end or beginning of a non-anchored expression doesn't add any value anyway.

Comment: constructed this http://jsperf.com/line-endvs-line-end-after any one please dare to look into the perfomance..(my chrome crashed)!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter what is present after `$` (not the escaped literal dollar), since it signifies the end of line and **nothing** can be there *after* the line ends.